# Direct Binding on DataGrid Column

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I have the following `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CommentaryGrid"
          ...
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCommentary, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CommentaryCollection}"
          Helpers:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=SearchTextBox, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Event ID" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding event_id}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Team" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding team, Converter={StaticResource NullTeamToBlankStringConverter}}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bookie" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding bookie}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding type}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding value}"/>
    ...
```

`CommentaryCollection` is defined via

```
public ObservableCollection<Taurus.Commentary> CommentaryCollection { ... }
```

I need to not merely display the `Taurus.Commentary.team` property for an object, but first test another property for a condition (using my `NullTeamToBlankStringConverter`). So I want to pass the entire `Taurus.Commentary` object to my column binding. I can change the column definition to

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Team" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Items, ElementName=CommentaryGrid, Converter={StaticResource NullTeamToBlankStringConverter}}"/>
```

To bind to the `ItemCollection`, but this does not enable me to test for the object in each row (using my converter). In the converter using the `ItemCollection` approach, I can cast to `ItemCollection` and check `CurrentItem` but this will only give me the selected item and hence the same value for all rows. How can I bind to the entire `Taurus.Commentary` Item of the `ItemSource`?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Binding Path=.` to bind to the entire data context (for an item template, thats an item in the collection).

In your case, it would look like:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource NullTeamToBlankStringConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. This is the solution I went for. It does not seem like the `MultiValueConverter` was required in my case.

Comment: @Killercam yeah, it wouldn't be unless you also needed the collection for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Use [**IMultiValueConverter**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pass the current object binding as second parameter.

```
<DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NullTeamToBlankStringConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Items" ElementName="CommentaryGrid"/>
            <Binding Path="."/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

NullTeamToBlankStringConverter needs to implement IMultiValueConverter instead of IValueConverter.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Most appreciated.

Comment: I thought you need both Items collection and current object for your algorithm but in case you are just interested in current object instance then `IValueConverter` as suggested by BradleyDotNET is a way to go.